# Remove Urine from Amana In-Wall Heating/Air-conditioning Unit

Tags: heating, air-conditioning

I just moved into a new apartment and noticed that when I turn the fan up high on the in-wall heating/ac unit there is a strong smell of urine. I swear that someone peed in it. Is there some way to open the thing up and look? The one that I have [looks like this](https://images.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cpsc.gov%2Fs3fs-public%2FRecall.2014.14263.PTAC%252520Generic%252520Unit_LARGE.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cpsc.gov%2FRecalls%2F2014%2Fgoodman-company-recalls-air-conditioning-and-heating-units&docid=DkOpsX2BuXliCM&tbnid=Uqgy8m0JdSl5eM%3A&vet=1&w=800&h=372&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim).

Comment: You posted a link to one that was recalled for risk of fire.  If that's the *exact* one you've got, that smell might be something melting...  I wouldn't expect a contamination smell to *only* show up on high.  Given it's an apartment, do you have the opportunity to ask the maintenance person, who would probably a) already have experience with the units and their maintenance, and b) appreciate not having a tenant taking it apart.

Comment: If it was peed it there is a chance that it was a dog.

Answer (score 1):

If there truly is urine or dried up remains of urine in the heater one way to clean it up is to douse and wipe it up with a product such as "Nature's Miracle" which neutralizes the odor causing organics in urine and its by-products.